# SQL table to classes

Tags: c#, object-model

I have a modelling question that I need help understanding.

I have a table called Employee and a table called Office. There is a 1 to many relationship between the classes (1 employee has one office and one office has multiple employees).

The goal is to create classes from those tables and I have found two ways:

1:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string Name   { get; set; }
    private Office Office { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    private string OfficeName { get; set; }
}
```

2:

```
public class Employee
{
    private string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Office
{
    private string OfficeName       { get; set; }
    private List<Employee>Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Which way is the correct way to model this ?

Comment: Is my question not understandable ?

Comment: I guess both ways are valid

Comment: You're couldn't would'nt've even compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the second approach to be easier to work with (more natural). Reason being, when you model your data this way:

```
public Class Employee
{
    string Name {get; set;}
}

public Class Office
{
    string OfficeName {get; set}
    List<Employee>Employees {get; set}
}
```

You can create these tables (or use [entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx) to create the tables for you) in the following manner:

```
// Office table             // Employee table
-----------------           ----------------------------------
| Id(PK) | Name | --------> | Id(PK) | OfficeId(FK) | Name |  
-----------------           ----------------------------------

// PK: Primary Key
// FK: Foreign Key
```

The `one-to-many` relationship is represented via the `FK` in the `employee` table and the `employee` has a `FK` to the office where he/she belongs. Then by using simple `joins` you can get all info you need from the tables. e.g.

Get all `employees` for an `office`

```
    SQL: SELECT Offices.OfficeId, Offices.Name, Employees.Name 
         FROM Offices
         JOIN Employees ON Offices.Id = Employees.OfficeId
         WHERE Offices.Name = 'some_name'
    // Or you can use LINQ had you had used Entity Framework
```

This would've been a bit more complicated if you had used your first approach.

Comment: Would it also be possible to show employee information (employee name and employee office) on a a screen through the UI this way (the employee object does not have any office property)?

Comment: @uba2012 you can, you will have to go through the office though. To show all the employees in all offices you can use the query above (not tested =]) and once the user wants to zero in into one of the employees then you have everything you need by adding the employee id to the query above. As an alternative, you can also add the office name as a property to the employee that you populate via a trigger (if you don't care about repeated data) or populate it on the fly after you query the office.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I will a office property to the employee class this way I can navigate from the employee object to office and the other way around too. The database cannot be changed I am only interested in class design so I cannot use EF to create tables.

Comment: @uba2012 yeah adding the property to employee will probably make things simpler. That sounds like a good plan.